# Footer is spazzy on some pages and not others

Tags: html, css

Here's my [website](http://viddir.com) (a constant work in progress).

It's based on PHPmotion. Unfortunately, the footer is a little spazzy.

On pages like this:
[Viddir.com](http://viddir.com) and [this](http://viddir.com/videos/load/recent), it's completely normal.

But, on other pages like:
[This](http://viddir.com/page.php?page=2) and [this](http://viddir.com/videos/10/dragonzball-p), it's screwed up.

What could be causing this?

Comment: You need to post html and not expect us to View Source on your page.

Comment: please post some code. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the correct one you showed, the `div.wrapper2` contains only the main content of the page. In the spazzy one, the `div.wrapper2` also contains the `div.footer` element (and in fact contains the entire content of the page). You'll need to add another `</div>` tag in the proper place (before the footer) in order to close the `div.wrapper2`.

Comment: Adding a </div> seems to have done the trick, even though everything was shown as closed. Anyway, appreciate it. :)

Comment: no problem...I prefer to use the Inspect Element feature in Chrome/Safari where you can show which menus are collapsed. You could have an unclosed <div> tag basically anywhere in there. I just glanced at it, so adding a </div> right above the footer might have screwed something else up if it wasn't in the right place. But glad it works for now, at least.